# WordPress plugin extend without changing core

Tags: wordpress

I am using the WordPress plugin for newsletter subscription. I want to change the format for the mail its sending to user but don't want to edit core cause when anyone upgrade plugin all changes will flushed away so anyone knows how to rightly edit the plugin files without making changes in its core files thanks for the help in advance.

```
<body style="background-color: #ddd; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
        <br>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666;">
                    <div style="text-align: left; max-width: 500px; border-top: 10px solid #43A4D0; border-bottom: 3px solid #43A4D0;">
                        <div style="padding: 10px 20px; color: #000; font-size: 20px; background-color: #EFEFEF; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd">
                            <?php echo get_option('blogname'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding: 20px; background-color: #fff; line-height: 18px">

                            <?php echo $message; ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

This the code in which i don't want blog name but want the logo of the blog and also want to change that style which is given on the html tags directly.

```
function mail($to, $subject, $message) {

        ob_start();
        include NEWSLETTER_DIR . '/subscription/email.php';
        $message = ob_get_clean();

        Newsletter::instance()->mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
```

This might be a function to include the email template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [filters and actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), which can be specified by a plugin to give other scripts/plugins the opportunity to work with your plugin.

More specifically, hopefully you can find something like this:

```
$email_body = apply_filters( 'amazingnewsletter_email_body', $email_body );
```

This means that you can filter (aka, make changes to) the variable $email_body within your own plugin/theme. If you just want this for your current website, it's easiest to place these directly in functions.php.

However, **the actual hook you are going to use depends entirely on the plugin**. And even then, the plugin may not offer the ability to edit the body with actions or filters.

I suggest reading the WordPress.org codex about actions and filters to get a better understanding of how they work. They are very powerful.

Comment: I am trying to edit the style and want to add my blog logo into that file is that possible without making changes in core?

Comment: The "core" of wordpress are the files that *do not* reside in the `/wp-content/` folder. However, you don't want to edit plugins directly either. You want to make your changes to your active theme's `functions.php` file. As I mentioned, how you actually make the edits depends on the plugin. It could be that it is not extensible at all, and you simply can't edit the template. You just have to look at the source code of the plugin to find out!

Comment: I have edited my ques with the code now can u tell me how can i make that edit.

Comment: That code contains no hooks of any kind that you can manipulate, unfortunately. What about the lines of code which include this file? You may be able to change the location of the file which is being included (which you can then point to your theme folder).

Comment: you mean that i can copy this file and point that file instead of this file?

Comment: Hopefully you can do that. But it depends on if the plugin which is including the file makes the file changeable. Post the function that is including the template (something like `include( PATH . '/newsletter.php' );`

Comment: this can done but when the plugin update all this changes will revert back so we cant do that

Comment: I need to see the include code before I can tell you if you can or can't modify the included template.

Comment: It seems your plugin is not friendly to developers, there are no hooks to allow you to edit the content of the email template outside of editing the plugin file directly. There is not much you can do here. You should suggest the plugin author to allow the included file path to be ["filtered"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) so that you may use your own template.

Comment: Ok i will tey to talk with plugin author thanks for your help :)